# pcap_close() crashes if handle is NULL

Tags: c, pcap, libpcap

Is it expected that `pcap_close(NULL)` segfaults? I'm observing this behaviour on `libpcap-1.7.4-2ubuntu0.1`. The `man` page does not say anything about behvaiour of the function for a `NULL` `pcap_t *`. I googled and could not find anything either.

Comment: you found your answer: protect the call against NULL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answers are correct. And in general (not specific to `pcap_close`), unless something is **documented** to accept a null pointer and treat it specially, the default assumption should always be that passing a null pointer is a violation of the interface contact, since a null pointer is **not a valid pointer** to whatever the function is documented to expect to receive a pointer to.

Answer (score 4):

From [the manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pcap_close):

> ```
> #include <pcap/pcap.h>
> void pcap_close(pcap_t *p);
> ```
>
> `pcap_close()` closes the files associated with `p` and deallocates resources.

It looks pretty obvious that the function is meant to be used with a *valid* pointer. A `NULL` pointer has no "files associated" or "resources" that need to be deallocated. The function uses the variable `p` assuming that it is a pointer to a valid `pcap_t` type. Passing in `NULL` makes it dereference `NULL` and of course that leads to a segmentation fault.

Looking at [the source code](https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/libpcap/blob/0103d2880a8f6e78fe001fe35f8be958eeda81eb/pcap.c#L3889) this is even more obvious:

```
void
pcap_close(pcap_t *p)
{
    if (p->opt.device != NULL)
        free(p->opt.device);
    p->cleanup_op(p);
    free(p);
}
```

This behavior is pretty common and you'll find it in almost every C library function that is used to close/free/clean a previously requested resource. In C the `NULL` check is *almost always* left to the caller, if not you'll most probably find it explicitly written in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

No documentation? just check the [source code](https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/libpcap/blob/master/pcap.c):

```
void pcap_close(pcap_t *p)
{    
    if (p->opt.device != NULL)

        free(p->opt.device);

    p->cleanup_op(p);

    free(p);
}
```

the first instruction reads `p->opt.device` which has undefined behaviour if `p` is `NULL`.

Protecting against `NULL` would be an easy enhancement. On the other hand, the crash is deterministic and can be easily debugged when passed a null pointer.

Comment: It would be easy, not an easy *enhancement*. Rather it would cover up bugs in the caller that are currently caught.

Comment: yes. "On the other hand, the crash is deterministic and can be easily debugged when passed a null pointer" as my answer ends. `fclose` fails when passed `NULL` but `free` is guaranteed to work… go figure.